# Shipping is not shows at checkout in magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, shipping

When I add a product in the cart it shows grand total with shipping charges included as you can see in the first image.[image]

But when I go for checkout at shipping method options then it shows "Sorry, no quotes are available for this order at this time." as you can see in the second image [image]
and I can't proceed forward from here....
Please solve this problem
Thank you

Comment: may be issue with theme

Comment: no , there is no theme issue

Comment: Do you have enabled at least one shipping method?

Comment: i have created this shipping by applying rule from shopping cart price rule...so it should be apply without enabling any shipping method